# how to print ENERGY in a simple rpl example like rpl-udp

Tags: cooja

I want to print a simple message in mrhof function.
in core>net>rpl I write mrhof.c in makefile. then in rpl-conf.h I change  RPL_DAG_MC_NONE to  RPL_DAG_MC_ENERGY.
in mrhof.c in calculate_path_metric there is a message to print. for example I want to print Energy.
when I run one of examples like udp-rpl in cooja why I can't see the message in mote output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your message use `PRINTF` macro. All `PRINTF`s (capped) are macros for `printf` (small).

For enabling this macro you should change the `DEBUG` constant value.

Add this to your code:

```
#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT
```

This snippet would enable your `PRINTF` macros.

For disabling debug mode and not printing any message written by `PRINTF` macro change to this:

```
#define DEBUG DEBUG_NONE
```